# Java Beginner Guidance

Tags: java

How do you write a Java program that accepts number as input and based on the value entered, displays a message?
Like
"1" displays "Yes"
"2" displays "No"

Comment: Check this out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-read-input-from-console-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you will want to look into is the Java Scanner. You can import it via `import java.util.Scanner;` To make a new Scanner which reads from the console you will write:

```java
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Scanners are very versatile, so they are built to read from any input stream. This could be a file, a String, or many other things. Just like `System.out` is an output stream to the console, `System.in` is an input stream from the console.
For more information you can read the scanner documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Now with your scanner created to get a number input we can use the `nextInt()` method.

```java
int input = userInput.nextInt();
```

Here is a simple program similar to what you described.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerInputTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter Input > ");
        int input = userInput.nextInt();
        
        if(input == 1){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else if(input == 2){
            System.out.println("No");
        }else{
            System.out.println("I don't Know");
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are just starting out please try your best to read through documentation, and don't just copy and paste answers from here. Try to tinker and change things to get a better understanding.
If you are going to be making a lot of console programs, I highly recommend also looking into [switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), as if else statements will eventually become very bloated the more branches you need.